# Access denied after adding Active Directory group to shared folder

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-share

I'm trying to automate file sharing process and I started by creating some Active Directory groups for each permission:

`USR_TEST_GROUP_RD`, `USR_TEST_GROUP_WR`, `USR_TEST_GROUP_FULL`

I've added some Active Directory users to those groups and added those 3 groups to a folder for them to access, but I'm sill getting an Access Denied message.  Why?

Comment: Are the folders in question shared?  They need to be.

Comment: yes, they are..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The users will have to log out and then log back in again to have their security token updated with the new groups. In a testing scenario like yours it's entirely possible that this wasn't done after the group add. When this happens you will experience exactly what you found out: access-denied errors when the permissions say they should be allowed.